# echoing symbols in terminal/bash

Tags: bash, command-history

Why am I not able to use "!" when trying to echo a message in terminal? For example:

```
echo -e "Hello\nWorld!"
```

bash returns the following command:

```
bash !: event not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `!` character is called "bang" and `bash` uses it for recalling command history. You can use it four ways:

```
!<firstFewCharsOfPreviousCommand>
```

example:

```
!rm
```

That will go to the last command you executed that began with "rm" and execute the whole thing.  Be *careful* when repeating potentially destructive commands like rm, as you may unintentionally execute another one than you thought you would. Above is illustration only, using bash's `CTRL-R` reverse search function is a much safer alternative.

```
!<indexInCommandHistory>
```

example:

```
!433
```

The index is the number that appears next to the command when you run the `history` command.

```
!!
```

No example necessary as that's all there is to it. It re-executes the immediately previous command (same as up arrow on most Linux distributions).

```
!$
```

Example:

```
# ls -lh /etc/fstab
# vi !$
```

Another literal, when bash executes this, the `!$` is replaced by the last word (string of characters without whitespace)

As you can see with the last one, you can even use it as part of a larger or different command. Another example of that with `!!`:

```
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]# echo hey
hey
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]# echo !!
echo echo hey    <-- printed to stderr so you know what !! was expanded to 
echo hey
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]#
```

If you want bash to, for whatever reason, view the character as a literal and not try to interpret it, you put the text in single quotes:

```
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]# echo -e "Hello\nWorld!"
-bash: !": event not found
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]# echo -e 'Hello\nWorld!'
Hello
World!
[root@hypervisor libsceptre]#
```

The reason your command isn't working is because it's trying to find the last command you wrote that began with a double quote (the functionality described in my first example) and can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for answering such a silly question Joel Davis! Cheers

Comment: +1 for a great answer. I added an explanation of the two line output of `echo !!`. It took me a little while to figure it out so I thought I'd point it out. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not a problem, clarity is key.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use history expansion (and you obviously don't) then you should rather disable it than learn the strange quoting and inhibition rules.

`set +H` or `set +o histexpand` gets you rid of it. You can check whether it is active by `echo $-` ("H" shows it being active) or `set -o` (`histexpand`).

Comment: I would hope that the questioner would take this opportunity to get to grips with history expansion, since it's really quite useful..

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the bang:

`echo -e "Hello\nWorld"\!`
**Note:** Having the bang outside of the quotes is intentional. Otherwise `\!` is echod.

Comment: What happens if you remove the backslash...?

Answer (score 1):

The special meaning of `!` is still active inside double quotes. `!` is a shell keyword that for instance takes an integer n as argument and runs the n'th command in your shell history. Use single quotes or escape the character to avoid confusion.

You can read more about history command expansion in `man history`.

Comment: Appreciate the quick feedback sir!

Comment: Clarification: the `!` _keyword_ is something else: it's the POSIX keyword used to negate a pipeline exit status. `man history` is unlikely to document **`bash`**'s or any shell history command or mechanism (though on some system, it may document the `readline`'s libhistory API which is similar to `bash`'s since `bash` uses a modified version of `readline`). Refer to the `bash` manual instead.